# Folland Chapter 6 Problem 20b

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n \in L^\infty(X,M,\mu)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$, $\sup_n ||f_n||_\infty < \infty$, and $f_n \to f$ a.e.. Suppose $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. We must show $f_n \to f$ in the weak* topology (viewing $L^\infty$ as a subspace of the dual of $L^1$).

My question is why we need $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite. What is wrong with the following proof? We are asked to show that for each $g \in L^1$, $\int f_ng \to \int fg$. But doesn't this follow directly from Dominated convergence theorem since $f_ng \to fg$ a.e. and $|f_ng| \le Mg \in L^1$ for each $n$, where $M := \sup_n ||f_n||_\infty < \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite. Nothing is wrong with your proof. $L^\infty$ is indeed always a subspace of the dual of $L^1$ (i.e. even if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite). Probably Folland added the $\sigma$-finite assumption so that $L^\infty$ would be all of the dual of $L^1$, but, as already stated, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mu$ is not $\sigma$ finite, then you cannot conclude that the dual of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$ but only that $L^\infty$ is contained in the dual of $L^1$. Anyway your proof works.

Comment: Why do we need the dual of $L^1$ to be $L^\infty$? We just need $L^\infty$ to be a subspace.

Comment: yes, it is enough to be a subspace. Functions in $L^\infty$ are in the dual of $L^1$ even if the measure is not $\sigma$ finite. So you are perfectly right.

Comment: Thanks. Also, even in finite measure spaces, it need not be the case that $(L^1)^* = L^\infty$.

Comment: Actually the necessary and sufficient conditions for the dual of $L^1$ to be $L^\infty$ is that the measure be localizable and
have the finite subset property. A sigma-finite or a finite measure satisfies both

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking the other way around. My apologies